# Flutter Dropdown selectedValue(argument from previous screen) not getting updated

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

The dropdown selected value is not getting updated on the flutter screen. The initial value is coming as an argument from the previous screen. I have initialized the variable globally and am using a setstate(). Using a stateful widget.

Comment: please provide code

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem. Do it as a [minimal-reproducible-problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make it even better.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the minimum line of code in that screen then you can use `StatefulBuilder` or you can use stream variable and listen that variable using `StreamBuilder()`.

You can learn more about stream from here. [StreamBuilderDemo](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/exploring-streambuilder-in-flutter-5958381bca67)